# Loading a .X model in DirectX 9

Tags: c++, directx, 3d, .x

I'm trying to make my first 3D demo for my portfolio but I'm having problems loading in multiple .X files so that I might be able to make a simple game.

I've worked through the msdn tutorials and Frank Luna's book that show how to load in one mesh. I even tried to mod franks demo code but I've found his code only does what he intended to. Modding it is just a complete headache.

I'm wondering if anyone knows and good help libs or websites with example code, that can take the hassle out of loading .X models into a game and allow me to move them etc

Answer (score 2):

When I was learning DirectX 9, [this](http://www.toymaker.info/Games/html/3d_models.html) site was a good place to look for information.

In a nutshell, you have to call `D3DXLoadMeshFromX` or one of its derivative functions to load the mesh object from a file (or memory).

You cannot "move" the object per se, you have to push/pop matrices to accumulate a translation/rotation for each object. e.g for a rotation:

```
float fAngle = 2.f;
D3DXMATRIXA16 matWorld;
D3DXMatrixIdentity(&matWorld); // Identity Matrix
D3DXMatrixRotationY( &matWorld, fAngle );
g_pd3dDevice->SetTransform( D3DTS_WORLD, &matWorld );
```